# How to save the content of 50 rows in Google Sheets as txt. file with Google Apps Script

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am looking at a table with 2,000-10,000 rows and need to save the content of 50 rows in a txt file, each line in the txt. file should be 1 row. In addition the the delimiter needs to be a "|".

---

Table given:

```
A1  T   B1  C1  ...

A2  T   B2  C2  ...
```

---

saved in `txt.` file like:

```
A1|T|B1|C1|...

A2|T|B2|C2|...
```

---

How do I need to loop through the table to create for 50 rows a new file including the content?

```
function getTxtFiles(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test");

    var folderName = 'Test Folder';
    var folderID = 'Test Folder ID';
    var documentName = 'Test_1.txt'
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);

  var data = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = data.getValues();
  var rows = "";   

for (var a = 0; a < data[a].length; a++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < values[i].length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      if (values[i][j]) {
        rows = rows + values[i][j];
          }
    rows = rows + "|";
        }
      }
    }

    var sss = DriveApp.createFile(documentName,rows,MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sss.getId());
    var parents = file.getParents();
    parents.next().removeFile(file);
    folder.addFile(file); 

}
```

I would like to achieve that the script is creating from a table with`2,000 rows and with 40 columns`, 40 x txt. files and each file includes the content of 50 rows, each row as 1 line in the txt. file.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
function txtFileCreator(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); // will give you all data cells in a 2D array
  var text = "";
  var count = 0;
  var flag = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    flag = true;    
    for (var j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++)
      text += data[i][j] + " | ";

    text += "\n";

    if ((i+1) % 50 == 0){
      count++;
      createF(text, count);
      text = "";
      flag = false;
    }
  }

  if (flag)
    createF(text, ++count);
}

function createF(content, count){
  DriveApp.createFile("File " + count, content, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
}
```

It worked perfectly for me, I tried with a test sheet with your kind of ranges and it creates the right files with just 50 lines each.

Comment: For me it does not work perfectly, every second file is saved blank without content.

Could you help?

Comment: I've updated the answer to fix the code, it was calling the createF function at the end regardless of anything, so if there were entries left (say if you had 50) rows populated, it would create an empty file, now it checks if there are rows left with the flag boolean variable

Answer (score 0):

#### Flow:

- `values` is a 2D array. Join the inner array using `|` and outer array with `\n`
- Use `str.match(regex)` to get a array of 50 rows each
- Create file for each string in the array.

#### Snippet:

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('[OUTPUT_FOLDER_ID]')
values.map(function(row){return row.join('|')})
  .join('\n')
  .match(/((?:.*\n){50}|(?:[\s\S]+$))/g)
  .forEach(function(str,i){ folder.createFile('textFile'+ i, str})
```

#### References:

- [Folder#createFile](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createFile(String,String))
- [String#match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: Every last file will be returned with 1 row only. I don't understand why - Can you clarify that?

Comment: @Tim I think i fixed it

Comment: it still returns the last file with only 1 row included.

Comment: @Tim Check now.